# How to include anchor tags (class ID's) to login redirect?

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, tags, anchor

I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-login-woocommerce/ on wordpress and it redirects perfectly, but if there is a link with an anchor tag it discard the anchor after redirect. How can I include the anchor tags on the redirect?

This is where the redirect happens:

```
function xoo_el_redirect_endpoints(){
    
    if( xoo_el_helper()->get_general_option( 'm-ep-success' ) !== "yes" ) return;

    add_filter( 'xoo_el_login_redirect', function( $redirect ){
        return add_query_arg( 'login', 'success', $redirect );
    } );
     
    add_filter( 'xoo_el_register_redirect', function( $redirect ){
        return add_query_arg( 'login', 'success', $redirect );
    } );
}
add_action( 'init', 'xoo_el_redirect_endpoints' );
```

And I added this snippet to test the anchor tag, but this is redirecting the whole site to '/#gids':

```
function xoo_cu_el_redirect($url){
    return $url .'/#gids';
    }
    
    add_filter( 'xoo_el_login_redirect', 'xoo_cu_el_redirect' ); //for login
    add_filter( 'xoo_el_registration_redirect', 'xoo_cu_el_redirect' ); // for registration
```

Comment: The URL fragment does not get send to the server in the first place, so you can't access it there to add it to your redirect URLs. If you _know_ which ID value you want to add, you'd still have to figure out how exactly this plugin performs its redirect - because with `add_query_arg` you won't be able to add a fragment to a URL either.

Comment: Hi CBroe, there is a handler file that preform the login:
if ( ! empty( $_POST['xoo_el_redirect'] ) ) {
     $redirect = sanitize_url( $_POST['xoo_el_redirect'] );
    }

    $redirect = apply_filters( 'xoo_el_login_redirect', wp_validate_redirect( $redirect ), $user );

    $success_notice = apply_filters( 'xoo_el_login_success_notice', '<i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.__( 'Login successful', 'easy-login-woocommerce' ), $user );

    do_action( 'xoo_el_login_success', $user );

Comment: But that checks for a POST parameter named `xoo_el_redirect`. And the action it executes there at the end, `xoo_el_login_success`, also doesn't sound as if it was in charge of actually redirecting.

Comment: _"And I added this snippet to test the anchor tag, but this is redirecting the whole site to '/#gids'"_ - what exactly do you mean by that? That it happens for _every_ URL you click on?

Comment: If I add the anchor tag to my url and login it redirects to the anchor tag perfectly and your logged in then. But if I go to any other url on my website and I log in it redirects to that page, but it adds the anchor tag. So that clearly didn't work.

Comment: There is a piece of code in the xoo-el-login-section.php file that might do the redirect:
$redirect  = xoo_el_helper()->get_general_option( 'm-red-login' );
$redirect  = !empty( $redirect ) ? $redirect : sanitize_text_field( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

Comment: _"So that clearly didn't work."_ - I would probably rather say, it does not match what you intended to achieve. What _exactly_ that is, I am still unclear on though. What is the difference between "when I log in", and "when I go to another page and log in"?

Comment: Here is the url to the site I'm working on https://jeug.co.za/skolier/. What I achieved as of yet, is to add a login popup to restrict users from viewing the content and only after login can see it. The redirect to the same page works perfectly, it's only when you want it to redirect to the anchor tag on that page for example https://jeug.co.za/skolier/#gids it discards the anchor tag. So I am trying to figure out where I can add this to accept anchor tags.

Comment: Like I said, the fragment portion of the URL does not get send to the server in the first place - so you have no way of _knowing_ about the `#gids` portion of the URL on the server side. You could for example try and add a hidden field to your login form, that you then put this ID into - then you'd have access to it on the server side, and could add it as the fragment of the redirect URL there again.

Comment: Okay, thank you CBroe for your advise. I'll try and do that then.